# Is it safe to host my applications entire backend code on GitHub?

Tags: node.js, express, security, github, backend

I know that pushing my frontend code on GitHub is absolutely safe. But what concerns me is my backend code. I want to showcase my server-side coding skills to my future recruiters. But what if my backend code has a **serious vulnerability** in it and someone reads my code and exploits the vulnerability? So basically what I am trying to say is I can push my normal project's backend source code on GitHub but is it worth it to host the backend code of a production website which is hosted on cloud and exploiting it can cost me money as well as lose the users of that app?

Answer (score 1):

yes if you write your code correctly and safe;
but there is always chance of serious vulnerability but may some kind people review your code, detect it and fix it for you;
it’s a double edge sword.
but if you are an intermediate programmer suggested you don’t publish your code public